# How to create web-service from wsdl and xsd files in NetBeans?

Tags: web-services, netbeans, xsd, wsdl

My task is to crate web-service in NetBeans (using Tomact) from **wsdl** and two **xsd** files. 
I don't understand what should I do with xsd files? What sequence of steps?

I've tried to crate "Web service from WSDL" in NetBans, but can't figure out how I should use xsd.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services are described by a series of WSDL and XSD files, The WSDL elements that describe the services are separated into various files based on their level of abstraction. Data type definitions are separated from service descriptions and placed into XSD files. You can follow [this](http://rphgoossens.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/developing-a-contract-first-jax-ws-webservice/) for development on Netbeans with contract first approach

Comment: the wordpress link above  is malicious with some some sort of flash exploit

Answer (score 0):

For WSDL and XSD, they are just XML, you can create them from scratch or modify based on an existing one in any editor.

Specifically, for how to start from WSDL and XSD in Netbeans, please refer to the following link for details:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/webservices/conWebServiceDevelopmentCycle.html